# Как заставить selenium webdriver очищать полученные запросы при каждой итерации?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Уже практически неделю я пытаюсь найти ответ на вопрос, как запретить selenium-wire сохранять в памяти запросы предыдущей итерации.

```
driver.get(project_url)
    h1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1').text
    bInfo = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Info').text
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.path.endswith('.txt'):
        response = request.response

        if response:
            print(f'URL: {request.url}')
            print(f'Body: {response.body}')
```

Это часть цикла, который забирает теги ,

Но когда я пытаюсь забрать requests, с каждой новой итерацией, я получаю результаты предыдущих итераций. По итогу у меня получается огромный список повторяющихся элементов.
Браузер сохраняет все полученные requests в течение сессии.
Я пытался чистить cache, удалять cookies но никакого результата это не дало.
В идеале хотелось бы выводить в json request после каждой итерации рядом с h1 и bInfo.
Буду рад любым мыслям.

Comment: `del driver.requests` пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо, забыл отметить что ваш ответ помог мне!